# Rails / ActiveAdmin - how to pass custom data from controller into content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a custom page that is going to pull some data and format it to so it can be displayed in a table. This is a very simplified version:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "My Custom Page" do
  controller do
    @data = [
      { name: "foo"},
      { name: "bar"}
    ]
  end

  content do
    panel "My Panel" do
      table_for @data do
        column("Name") { |row| row[:name] }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run that, I get an error `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`
 because the variable `row` getting passed into the block is nil. How do I properly pass the `@data` object to the view?

Comment: I think you are misusing controller here and not actually defining anything in `@data` in this context. if you were to remove the `controller` block this may work. You are not actually "passing" anything as it seems `register_page` is just a view and essentially an empty controller action that causes it to render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the data within the view. While doing that you can access the `params` as if it were a controller.

```
content do
  data = Entity.find(params[:id]
end
```

This is not the Rails way, but I think within ActiveAdmin this is totally ok. If you had more complex data to load and process, you could create a service for it.

If you feel like you need to use use controller, you would do it like that:

```
controller do
  def index 
    # your code
  end
end
```

It is interesting, that you don't even need to call `super` - the page is rendered either way.

Comment: This works. ActiveAdmin definitely breaks some Rails conventions. Feels a little icky